# How to check the date of the non-current kernel on Debian

Tags: bash, debian, kernel

You get the **date** of the **current kernel** on Debian with (here: 2020-12-17):

```
user@pc:~$ uname -v
#1 SMP Debian 4.9.246-2 (2020-12-17)
```

But, how to check the **date** of the **non-current** (e.g. linux-image-4.9.0-13-amd64    4.9.228-1) kernel on Debian?
I can't see this with:

```
user@pc:~$ dpkg -l | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-4.9.0-13-amd64    4.9.228-1                         amd64        Linux 4.9 for 64-bit PCs
ii  linux-image-4.9.0-14-amd64    4.9.246-2                         amd64        Linux 4.9 for 64-bit PCs
ii  linux-image-amd64             4.9+80+deb9u12                    amd64        Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package)
```

And the follow command doesn't show this, too:

```
dpkg -s linux-image-4.9.0-13-amd64
```

Thanks

Comment: That's just the date that it was compiled. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @jordanm Yes, this is.

Answer (score 0):

My current kernel on ubuntu 20.04 is 5.4.0-58.

```
# uname -a
Linux mylaptop8 5.4.0-58-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 9 08:16:25 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

then the date is december the 9th. If I download the changelog I should have some clue about the date:

```
# apt-get changelog linux-image-5.4.0-58-generic | cat | head -n6
downloading :1 https://changelogs.ubuntu.com linux-signed 5.4.0-58.64 Changelog [90,7 kB]
linux-signed (5.4.0-58.64) focal; urgency=medium

  * Master version: 5.4.0-58.64

 -- Khalid Elmously <khalid.elmously@canonical.com>  Wed, 09 Dec 2020 02:30:56 -0500
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but on my Debian 9.13  I can't see the date with this.